# How to reference the composited PRIMARY KEY in table1 to table 2 as foreign key in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I having a problem with creating foreign key that pointing to a composite primary key in other table.

```
CREATE TABLE CityCountry(
    city_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(100),
    country_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(100),
    citycountry_id VARCHAR(105) PRIMARY KEY (city_code, country_code) 
)

CREATE TABLE FlightRoute(
    flightroute_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    flight_departureCountryCity VARCHAR(105),
    flight_id INT FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES Flight(flight_id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    flight_departureDateTime DATETIME,
    flight_arrivalDateTime DATETIME,
    aircraft_code VARCHAR(15) FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES Aircraft(aircraft_code)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    flight_order SMALLINT
)
```

I tried the solution in stackoverflow but didnt work out

```
alter table flightroute add constraint FK_FlightRoute_CityCountry foreign key FlightRoute(flight_departureCountryCity) references CityCountry (city_code, country_code)
```

Comment: If you have pk of 2 columns you shoud have 2 columns in routes table, citycode and contrycode and do fk on those 2 columns

Comment: is it possible to have 1 column foreign key in routes table that referencing to citycountry_id

Comment: Yes possible, make citycountry_id unique index in cities table and then reference it from routes as a fk

Comment: is it require alter table? because i could not help myself by using the DDL as u said

`CREATE TABLE FlightRoute(
 flightroute_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
 flight_departureCountryCity VARCHAR(105) FOREIGN KEY 
  REFERENCES CityCountry(citycountry_id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 flight_id INT FOREIGN KEY 
  REFERENCES Flight(flight_id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 aircraft_code VARCHAR(15) FOREIGN KEY 
  REFERENCES Aircraft(aircraft_code)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 flight_order SMALLINT
)`

Comment: is it my concept for adding two columns in table1 has been incorrect? because all i did now is to combine two columns value as the primary key value for cities table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a foreign key referenced columns shoud be `PK` or `unique index`. Since you already have a `PK` you can make your column a `unique index`:

```
create unique index UI_CityCountry
   on CityCountry(citycountry_id);
```

Now create `FK`:

```
alter table flightroute
add constraint FK_FlightRoute_CityCountry
foreign key (flight_departureCountryCity)
references CityCountry (citycountry_id)
```

Comment: i could not execute second query, it having Incorrect syntax nearly"FlightRoute"

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CityCountry(
    citycountry_id VARCHAR(105) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    city_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(100),
    country_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE FlightRoute(
    flightroute_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    flight_departureCountryCity VARCHAR(105) FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES CityCountry(citycountry_id),
    flight_id INT FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES Flight(flight_id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    flight_departureDateTime DATETIME,
    flight_arrivalDateTime DATETIME,
    aircraft_code VARCHAR(15) FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES Aircraft(aircraft_code)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    flight_order SMALLINT
);
```

That is, declare the primary key correctly in the first table and thenuse it in the second.

Personally, I prefer primary keys that are incremented numeric values, but I'm leaving your original types.